# Magento 2 remove Gift Cards Cart Summary

Tags: magento2, template, magento-2.2.5

Working to remove the Gift Card feature on Magento 2 Cart summary section. Having issue getting this working.
Have created the following file:

```
.../app/design/frontend/***/***/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml
```

The following code is not working to remove the giftcard block:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="cart.summary">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-giftcard" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading the first proposed solution which had already been tested, searched and found the module block in gift-card-account and this is the solution in the same file I was using in my question:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="cart.summary">
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.giftcardaccount" remove="true"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

As it may be useful for removing the gift card from the checkout page you can add/edit this file:

```
.../app/design/frontend/***/***/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="giftCardAccount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove it from the customer account page too: Remove this block via layout.xml: 'customer_account_navigation', which is originally added here: vendor/magento/module-gift-card-account/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

Comment: how to show gift option price on cart summary Magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the Gift Card Message block from the cart page I tried the layout block remove instructions but it throughs me a JS error in the console for missing gift-message component.

I found the below solutions that works for me in proper way by dislabling the gift message component for Cart page.

> Create File:

```
app/design/frontend/{YourThemePackage}/{yourtheme}/Magento_GiftMessage/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml
```

> Add XML instructions to disabled gift-message component:

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.order.actions.gift_options">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="giftOptionsCart" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Comment: how to show gift option price on cart summary Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

The `Gift Card` is in `module-gift-message` and not in `module_checkout`so :

> /app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themeName}/Magento_GiftMessage/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.order.actions.gift_options" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped me search in the modules to find the proper one. I'll post actual solution separately.

Comment: how to show gift option price on cart summary Magento 2?